# Replicate Wordpress Admin Posts Section with Category Limitation

Tags: wordpress

I would like to have WP Admin menu on the left that is called "Products". This menu will have the similar replication to "Posts". There will be submenus "All Posts", "Add New", and "Categories".

- The "All Posts" link will show only posts that are in the "products" category.
- "Add New" will automatically add the post with "products" category. The categories on the right will show all the sub categories of the "products" category.
- "Categories" link will be managing categories that are the subcategories of "products" category.

I wonder if anyone has ever done this before or if there are any plugin that can accomodate this. Any information or feedback is much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called **[Custom Post Types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)** (CPT).

You can add any type of your choice - like `Product` - to the already existing and well known types `Post` and `Page`. Categories and tags will be called **[Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies)**.

Comment: Yes, but this is way too complex because it screws up theming, has many other requirements in permalinks etc.